# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Instance on the Network

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection

I installed an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on my 32 bit Windows 7 machine.  I can see it and connect to it with SQL Server Management Studio locally but not on the network.

SQL Server Configuration Manager Settings

- SQL Server Browser is running (Log on As "NT AUTHORUITY\LocalService")
- Named Pipes for this instance are Enabled
- TCP/IP Enabled Dynamic ports are set to nothing the TCP Ports are set to 1433

In the Server Properties from SSMS

- Connections --> I have the "Allow remote connections to this server" box checked

The Firewall is turned off for testing

When I try to see this instance with a command prompt (sqlcmd -L) from another computer I get a list of network servers.  Sometimes it shows up and sometimes it doesn't.  If it shows up I still can't seem to connect and the error message number is 26.  If feels like there is some switch somewhere that needs to be turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am leaving this up there for any other users who have mental blocks occasionally... I had not turned off all the firewalls. In windows7 you have three different firewalls and you have to turn off the right one